# Override a ResourceDictionary's StaticResource in a .Resources tag

Tags: wpf, xaml

Basically I have a Theme.xaml file and I want to use a Storyboard defined in it in my MainWindow.xaml. I can manage to do that just fine, but I want to customize the Duration and BeginTime. I want to override these StaticResource from the TextBlock's Resources like so:

Theme.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">        
    <Storyboard x:Key="FadeIn">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="{StaticResource StoryboardDuration}" BeginTime="{StaticResource StoryboardBeginTime}">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut" />
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" ResizeMode="NoResize" Width="512" Height="512">
    <Window.Resources>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Theme.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Should fade in after 3 seconds" Opacity="0">
            <TextBlock.Resources>
                <!-- Define values for storyboard -->
                <sys:TimeSpan x:Key="StoryboardBeginTime">0:0:1</sys:TimeSpan>
                <Duration x:Key="StoryboardDuration">0:0:3</Duration>
            </TextBlock.Resources>
            <TextBlock.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="TextBlock.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource FadeIn}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </TextBlock.Triggers>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code above won't compile because StoryboardBeginTime and StoryboardDuration are not defined. But if I add the following at the top of the Theme.xaml's ResourceDictionary, it compiles but the values are not overwritten by the TextBlock.

```
<system:TimeSpan x:Key="StoryboardBeginTime">0:0:0</system:TimeSpan>
<Duration x:Key="StoryboardDuration">0:0:1</Duration>
```

Can anyone help me with that? Thank you.

Comment: From my understanding, your resource dictionary compiles before your Window, so the error is to be expected. Did you try referencing the BeginTime/Duration as Dynamic Resources from your Storyboard?

Comment: Thanks Michael. I changed Duration="" and BeginTime="" to DynamicResource and removed the 2 lines at the top of my Theme.xaml file. It compiles and runs, but still ignores what is defined in <TextBlock.Resources>